# How do I use arithmetic operators in updates in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following  *portfolio* document in MongoDB. Each portfolio includes an array of *securities* objects, like so:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f4271f7105c107b64157b6b"),
        "name" : "TestPortfolio",
        "securities" : [
                {
                        "shares" : 0,
                        "avgBuyPrice" : 0,
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5f4271f7105c107b64157b6c"),
                        "ticker" : "STOCK1",
                        "trades" : [ ]
                },
                {
                        "shares" : 0,
                        "avgBuyPrice" : 0,
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5f4271f7105c107b64157b6d"),
                        "ticker" : "STOCK2",
                        "trades" : [ ]
                },
                {
                        "shares" : 0,
                        "avgBuyPrice" : 0,
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5f4271f7105c107b64157b6e"),
                        "ticker" : "STOCK3",
                        "trades" : [ ]
                }
        ],
        "__v" : 0
}
```

I want to perform an update operation that edits the `avgSharePrice` field of a specific security object, by checking the `ticker` field. My main concern is that I want to perform the following calculation that involves the `shares` and `avgBuyPrice` fields:

What I'm trying to do is, when I increment `securities.shares` by **n** shares, say, I want to also update the **avgBuyPrice** of that security using the formula avgBuyPrice = (avgBuyPrice*securities.shares + price*n) / (securities.shares + n). Hence, I want to utlise the $add, $multiply and $divide operators in the update function. Is that possible or do I need to find() the parent document, make the updations manually and save() the parent document again? I'm using Mongoose and NodeJS.

To do this, I have tried the following query (assuming n = 5, price = 100)

```
db.portfolios.update( {"securities.ticker": "WIPRO"}, 
    [
        {$set: {"securities.$.avgBuyPrice": 
            { $divide: [ 
                $add: [
                    $multiply: [ 
                        "$securities.shares", "$securities.avgBuyPrice"],
                         $multiply: [5, 100]
                    ], 
                $add: [
                    "securities.shares", 5]
                ] } } } ] )
```

**Note: I am using Mongoose with NodeJS in a project, but testing my queries on the mongo client directly.**

**What I have tried so far:**

**1.** Using the **`$set` operator** in an update operation:

```
db.portfolios.update({"securities.ticker": "STOCK2"}, {$set: {"securities.$.avgBuyPrice": {$add: [10, 20]}}})
```

This gives me an error saying the operator is not valid for storage.

**2.** Using the **`$set` operator** in an update operation, as part of an **aggregation pipeline**:

```
db.portfolios.update({"securities.ticker": "STOCK2"}, [{$set: {"securities.avgBuyPrice": {$add: [10, 20]}}}])
```

This works, but it updates the `securities.avgBuyPrice` field for *all* securities objects.

I want to be able to use the **$add**, **$divide** and **$multiply** operators to perform the update. How do I go about this?

**3.** When I try using the "$securities.shares" field path or similar with an arithmetic operator in an aggregate operation, like so:

```
db.portfolios.aggregate({$set: {"securities.avgBuyPrice": {$add: ["$securities.shares", 20]}}})
```

I get an error saying the `$add` operator accepts only numeric or date types, not array. Why does this happen?

Since I am using NodeJS and Mongoose, do I need to `find()` the entire portfolio document, iterate to the sub-document I want to edit, make changes and then `save()` the entire document again?

Comment: Can you list down the operations that you are trying to do specifically ?

Comment: @KunalMukherjee Certainly. What I'm trying to do is, when I increment **securities.shares** by **n** shares, say, I want to also update the **avgBuyPrice** of that security using the formula **newABP = (avgBuyPrice\*oldShares + price\*newShares) / (oldShares + newShares)**. Hence, I want to utlise the $add, $multiply and $divide operators in the update function. Is that possible or do I need to `find()` the parent document, make the updations and `save()` the parent document again? I'm using Mongoose and NodeJS.

Comment: What are `oldShares` and `newShares` please update in the question details

Comment: @KunalMukherjee I have updated the question with the exact operation I am trying to construct a query for. Apologies, I had kept the question general but have made it more specific with details.

Comment: `db.collection.update` doesn't have the reference of the document which is currently being updated, in my opinion its better to `find` the document, update the document in memory in Javascript/node.js and `save` it back since you're using fields which are dependent on each other

Comment: In order to reference the values of multiple fields in a single operation, you will need to use the pipeline form of update that was added in MongoDB 4.2